# spaCy 3.4 Sentence segmenter permutations performing poorly on phrases without punctuation

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am attempting to use two of the four alternatives from spaCy for sentence segmentation, and all of them seem to perform equally bad on phrases without punctuation.  I am trying to utilize a solution such as these on spans of text that are blended and not diarized (speaker diarization).  My goal is to identify sentence boundaries and I thought the  linguistic parsing functionality might work well to split the phrases into individual sentence elements.

```
python version and spacy version with language models:  
============================== Info about spaCy ==============================

spaCy version    3.4.3                         
Location         /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy
Platform         macOS-12.6-arm64-arm-64bit    
Python version   3.10.8                        
Pipelines        en_core_web_sm (3.4.1), en_core_web_trf (3.4.1)
```

I tried the following methods (after uninstalling and reinstalling both the spaCy updates and also the appropriate language model updates:

Dependency parser - According to the docs (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd), this should work well if texts are closer to general purpose news or web text.  Here is my example:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("perfect how are you doing i'm ok good to hear that can you explain me a little bit more about the situation that you send me by email")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.text)
    print(token.text for token in doc)
```

- returns:

  perfect how are you doing i'm ok good to hear that can you explain me a little bit more about the situation that you send me by email

In using the spaCy statistical segmenter, I have the same results.  According to the docs, this statistical model ONLY provides the sentence boundaries (which is fine with me).  See below:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", exclude=["parser"])
nlp.enable_pipe("senter")
doc = nlp("perfect how are you doing i'm ok good to hear that can you explain me a little bit more about the situation that you send me by email")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.text)
```

- returns the same result, essentially no sentence boundaries

The documentation states that these models require a trained pipeline to provide accurate predictions.  I am using the https://spacy.io/models/en (https://spacy.io/models/en).  Is there something that I might be missing or not using correctly?  I would have expected that the syntax parsing (NP, VP, etc, etc) would assist in defining the boundaries) would have been able to at least identify one sentence boundary.  But without punctuation, I am getting the same span of text that I use as input.

Also, I tried using a different language model (en_core_web_trf (3.4.1)) but I am having issues with the environment not recognizing the installation is correct).  Separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to utilize a solution such as these on spans of text that are blended and not diarized (speaker diarization).

The issue is simply that the spaCy models are not trained for that task and won't do well. They're trained mostly on text from books or articles that reliably has punctuation.

What you can do is train the SentenceRecognizer with your own data. It might be that the task is just hard and performance still won't be great, but it should do better than the default models.

Answer (score 0):

You could semiautomatically infer the sentence boundaries, then capitalize them. That wouldn't be too hard.
Almost all your sentences start with personal pronouns (*I/You*), or else the auxiliary verb *Can* preceding the personal pronoun.

> *Perfect How are you doing I'm ok good to hear that Can you explain me a little bit more about the situation that you send me by email*

Comment: thank you.  I probably trivialized the problem to some degree just with the example sentence.  The utterances range from that one to "<name> this is my name is <name2> can i have an account number with you please yes our account number is <digits>  i'm calling from my personal mobile phones my phone line is down"

Comment: Ja4H3a, still that's easy to semiautomatically infer the sentence boundaries.

Comment: When you say "easy to semiautomatically infer the sentence boundaries", that's exactly what I thought that the spaCy library would do.  What approach would you recommend in this case, where the sentences are continuances of a conversation and my not have the pronouns in place - something like "Yeah, okay.  Hold on.  Can I get access via RDP", etc.   I had hoped that spaCy's built in capability for syntactic parsing and word associations to PoS would help to some degree.  .